# How to save db.Model class of flask in seprate file?

Tags: python, class, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have this **main.py** file which is working fine for me but I want to know is there any way to save the **class Contact(db.Modal)** into another "**.py**" file and use it in main.py file.

```
from datetime import datetime
from enum import unique
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask.wrappers import Request
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:@localhost/thecleandb'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Contact(db.Model):
    sno = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=False, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    phone = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True, nullable=False)
    msg = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=False, nullable=False)
    myDate = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=False, nullable=False)
    


@app.route("/contact", methods=['GET','POST'])
def contact():
    if (request.method=='POST'):
        name= request.form.get('name')
        email = request.form.get('myemail')
        phone_number = request.form.get('myphone')
        message = request.form.get('msg')
        database_entry = Contact(name=name, email=email, phone=phone_number, msg=message, myDate=datetime.now().date() )
        '''These lines are to add the database entry to the database we have created'''
        db.session.add(database_entry)
        db.session.commit()
        return render_template('contact.html')
    else :
        return render_template('contact.html')

if __name__ =='__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like that

```
from core.extensions import db


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'users'


    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)

    email = db.Column(db.String)

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

In your extension file :

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

And you can run your db in main.py with that ->

```
db.init_app(app)
```

I edited a basic app which can be useful and use that framework -> https://github.com/bmagnette/default_flask